# Switching back and forth from 12v to 48v

Tags: voltage, power-electronics

I need to be able to power a claw (2 wires) with 12V constantly. But sometimes i need to power it with 48V to increase strength for a few seconds then go back to 12 V.

I looked for a few solutions but i'm not sure..

1) i could use 2 relays switch and wiring my claw to the two relays and then disabling the 12V relay and enabling the 48V one when needed ?

2) Using something like a motor driver (similar to L298N? but it can't handle that much voltage) and using the analogWrite / PWMwrite to change the "speed" aka the volatge sent ?

3) linear regulator?

Note: I'm using a raspberry to control everything.

Comment: That could burn out the motor going to 4x the voltage and possibly 16x the power.  unless it is water cooled but you would just use stronger switch in parallel (lower Ron to higher V) and use one or the other protected by a series diode

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the 48V as the only power source and then PWM it down, using a FET, to ~12v (25% duty cycle) and then increase the PWM when you need more power.  But beware, as  Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy points out, that you could overheat the motor.  Time spent at the higher power should be carefully controlled.

To address your numbered items:

1. The dead time between relays could cause the motor to lose torqe and the claw would release.
2. As you mention, it only goes up to 46V. I'm not familiar with motor drivers, there could be one out there with a higher rating.
3. Do not use a linear regulator. It's just going to cause you heart ache with power dissipation and possibly other failures. There is too much power going on.

Comment: thanks ! the PWM solution looks  great. I think i'm gonna give a try with the IRF520 and a 48V DC. What do you think ? Edit: Looks like the IRF520 only output 24V max :/

Comment: @Owow IRFL110 is a 100V part.  Make sure you check for current and power though.